# How to make tab navigation between textboxes in QML?

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, qtquick2, qt-quick

I have a QML component (or whatever it is, just a file with Item in root) with border and `TextInput`, basically a standard textbox.

```
import QtQuick 2.7

Item {
    id: textBox
    clip: true

    property alias  inputText:       inputText.text
    property alias  mode:            inputText.echoMode
    property color  borderColor:     "gray"
    property int    borderWidth:     1

    Rectangle {
        id: rectInput
        anchors.fill: parent
        border.color: borderColor
        border.width: borderWidth
        radius:       4
    }

    TextInput {
        id: inputText
        anchors.fill:       parent
        anchors.leftMargin: 3
        verticalAlignment:  Text.AlignVCenter
        selectByMouse:      true
    }
}
```

I have a form with 2 of these components.

```
GridLayout {
    anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
    anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
    width: 400
    columns: 2
    rowSpacing: 10

    Text {
        id: textName
        clip: true
        text: "Name: "
    }
    TextBox {
        id: tboxName
        Layout.fillWidth: true
        height: 30
        KeyNavigation.tab: tboxPassword
    }

    Text {
        id: textPassword
        clip:  true
        text: "Password: "
    }
    TextBox {
        id: tboxPassword
        Layout.fillWidth: true
        height: 30
        mode: TextInput.Password
    }

    ...
}
```

How to make tab navigation between them? I tried to add `KeyNavigation.tab` but no effect.

btw does QML/Qt Quick really doesn't have any default tab handling between interactable components? So we have to always specify tabs manually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the one that receives the focus is `TextBox` which is an item that does not know how to handle it, so we must activate the `activeFocusOnTab` property and handle the event with `onActiveFocusChanged`:

```
import QtQuick 2.7

Item {
    id: textBox
    clip: true

    property alias  inputText:       inputText.text
    property alias  mode:            inputText.echoMode
    property color  borderColor:     "gray"
    property int    borderWidth:     1
    activeFocusOnTab: true // <--
    onActiveFocusChanged: if(activeFocus) inputText.focus = true // <--

   Rectangle {
        id: rectInput
        anchors.fill: parent
        border.color: borderColor
        border.width: borderWidth
        radius:       4
    }

    TextInput {
        id: inputText
        anchors.fill:       parent
        anchors.leftMargin: 3
        verticalAlignment:  Text.AlignVCenter
        selectByMouse:      true
        focus: true // <--
    }
}
```